# How can i create a view or layout like CalendarView of all months of the year?

Tags: android, layout, view, calendar

Hi im starting to developing in Android and search a lot of how to make an android layout like the image that is below. but Android Studio only has Calendar View.

Do you know a library with a similar calendar view[image]?

Or how can i make a similar View?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying out this: https://github.com/square/android-times-square it shows the calendar view as you want and it can be set up vía XML. Maybe [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/) page would fit you whenever you need a library.

Comment: Thanks for the tool but i need something more specific, because later i in my aplication i need to touch the month to see a Month view of the Calendar View  and this  already i had.

Comment: There is no such thing to select only the month. You may implement that with spinners.